# Is colour rendering in Chrome broken?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, colors

### PROBLEM:

Any colours in Chrome (images or CSS) look crunched. Have obviously seen this with my own sites but it can be seen on any site - as per the image attached.

See the guy's skin tones and the blue box below (Chrome left, Safari right).

---

### QUESTION:

Is there a setting that can be invoked via CSS/HTML which forces less fluro colours?

---

I posted this question to the Chrome DEV Group but was told by a moderator that I shouldn't be posting web development issues to that group. Hence me asking here if there's something I can do about it.

---

[image: Chrome renders inaccurate colour which can be seen on any website, including Google sites]

Comment: Jpg isn't really the best format for this. Just look at what happened to the font. First, replace this image with a lossless format. Otherwise, it's just a speculation on whether this is chrome or jpeg compression.

Comment: I tried it myself, didn't observe the difference. Here are my results, saved as png, which has lossless compression: http://imgur.com/a/4fOvp. I was on my gaming pc (windows) when trying this and didn't feel like getting my macbook, therefore I replaced safari with ms edge, but if there really was a bug, it would most likely be visible too. Provide each of the above source images in lossless format (e.g. png) and let us be the judge.

Comment: Tried in Chrome 57 on Mac OS X 10.12 and cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak Imgur converts my 24bit pngs into JPEGs, originals are Photoshop files from screenshots and the differences are just as dramatic (although the colours are obviously different). I see this on my Macbook Pro (here's a new screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/z8Ae0), my Mac Pro (see the Google image above), I've seen it on two other older Mac Pros in the last few months and have noticed the difference when switching browsers to test sites for at least two years (all using 10.11.6). Firefox is the same as Chrome (fluro) Safari matches Photoshop. I'm lost!